# Adding a rule based on dropdown options

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I use google sheets for work to track employees/contractors and salaries.

For instance, column A is salary and column B has a dropdown rule for stages of employment (hired, pending, quit, etc.)

In column A I have a function that calculates the sum (=SUM(A4:A17)

I'm wondering if there is a way for the sum function (column A) to automatically remove the cell value (while keeping the salary number) when the dropdown (column B) is changed from hired to quit.

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.